# trigger a script when mailbox recieves mail?

Tags: email, cron, polling, background-process

I want to process a particular mailbox when it receives mail, I know I could have cron check every n minutes for any mail, but wondering if there's a way to "listen" for mail rather than continually polling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a [.forward file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E-mail_forwarding)

You can pipe the message into any program or script you want, but also check if [procmail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procmail) can do what you want.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using postfix I'd suggest [aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487635/defining-a-messagle-handler-in-postfix/487666#487666) the mailbox you're interested in to a process that will do the work for you.  Then there's no polling.  The message comes in and goes directly to being processed.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your mail server, it may be possible to actually have any incoming message be delivered to a process.  Either in a .forward or by setting up something more advanced.  In exim you can setup a transport to run a command, for certain addresses.

Answer (score 2):

As [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6212/jason-punyon) and [Zoredache](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20267/zoredache) have already mentioned, you might be able to do this in the MTA itself.  Another possibility is to have [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) watch the mailbox file or maildir.

Answer (score 2):

if you dont have a mail-server on your own (root-access) - you could use a web service for that: http://cloudmailin.net (200mails/month for free) - works like charme and helped me out.